# Is it true that GCD$(\alpha,b)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $d=$GCD$(a,b)$, and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\alpha\cdot a+\beta \cdot b=d$.
Is it true that GCD$(\alpha,b)=1$?

Comment: Do you mean $b$ or $\beta$ in the second argument of gcd?

Comment: It isn't a typo, I meant b.

Comment: BTW you can use `$\gcd(a,b)$` to type $\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:
$$2\cdot4-1\cdot6=2.$$

Comment: Actually, $2$ and $-1$ are coprime, aren't they?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf yes, but those are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The question is about $\alpha$ and $b$. (Unless it's a typo, in which case I answered the wrong question.)

Answer (score 1):

Express $a=d \cdot a'$ and $b= d \cdot b'$, replace in your equation and see what happens! Be lucky

Comment: I was about deleting this answer because of the above discussion about a possible type, but it was just upvoted! :P